# No display after CMOS and BIOS reset

Tags: boot, windows-10, display, bios, cmos

I've got a very weird problem here, sorry to have such a specific case but I'm not sure what to do at this point.

So, this is for context I don't *think* it's related to the problem: I had [this problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/48qs4y/fix_update_kb3139907_and_cumulative_update/) which was causing problems starting due to a Windows Update (Windows 10). Hadn't gotten around to fixing it because the temporary fix was "don't turn off the system."

Here's the real problem: I had a **power outage**. But the *only* thing that went wrong is, I couldn't boot to Windows. Couldn't boot to safe mode, but could boot to console (I could get to Windows's EUFI "troubleshoot" thing). Might've been due to the aforementioned problem, might've been because the power outage messed with BIOS. So, after examining the former, I thought I'd adress the possibility of a BIOS problem. Looked it up, and I **turned off all power to the PC, and held the power button**, in other words a flea power drain.

Seems pretty innocuous, *but* now my PC **won't show a display** at all. Unplugged my graphics card, tried integrated graphics. Still nothing. It's not my monitors because they worked before I did this (after the power outage). Then I took out the `CMOS` battery for 10 minutes, held the power button down for 30 seconds (while unplugged). Still nothing. But it posts, (at least the motherboard LEDs turn on, the fans spin, everything as you'd think it should be). The **case speaker makes a barely audible ticking sound** (not a full beep). I only installed it *after* getting the problem so I don't know if the ticking is normal.

Don't think my specs are relevant, got a custom-built PC. Will post specs if asked for.

So, I'm not asking for any help with the Windows problem, I'll figure that out later ;). I would just like to know, now what to get my display back?

**TLDR**: No display when booting. `POST`s, no apparent hardware issues. Quick list of things that lead to the problem:

- Power outage caused (presumably unrelated) Windows problem
- Tried to fix by holding the power button down while unplugged (flea power drain... this resets `BIOS`, right?)

List of things I've tried to fix it:

- Took out `CMOS` battery, held power button down (while unplugged)
- Diagnosed and are in working order: monitor, graphics card, PSU. Motherboard LEDs turn on.

I'm at a loss, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Added info on case speaker. It ticks.

Comment: than get a case speaker first, it is cheap and worth to buy it, it works better than a universal debug card. If you can hear a signle beep when you power on the PC, it means the PC is normal, then you should check for the output monitor or the singal cable

Comment: Ok I got one. It's making a ticking noise, any idea what that might mean?

Comment: What is the pattern of the beep sound?  Let say 2 short 1 long or one single beep?  And what is your motherboard model?

Comment: I also had this problem, in my case it was my processor which was dead for some reason. After replacing it everything is working fine without any issue. Try switching processor or your motherboard.

Comment: @Bilo the it's one tick about every second, repeated, but it's clearly not "properly" beeping, only ticking.

Comment: For a normal repeated short beep, it indicated there is power issue, highly possible powersupply or motherboard failure. For processor, it usually having longest lifespan than other hardware components, it might be dead   but usually I prefer to check motherboard and  powersupply first. If you are just having some ticking instead of normal beep and you can see the motherboard LED is on, I think it is higher chance for the motherboard failure.

Answer (score 0):

this was like, forever ago, but i think the way i ultimately fixed it was to use my gigabyte backup bios as described in method three of [this guide](https://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php/697533-GUIDE-Forcing-backup-BIOS-on-Gigabyte-motherboards)